# App.xaml Object Reference Not Set To An Instance Of An Object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I recently started getting an error in my App.xaml after installing Blend 4, all my ViewModels now show an error of "Object Reference Not Set To An Instance Of An Object". I uninstalled Blend 4 and the errors went away for a few hours and are now back.

I've checked out every commit I've made till the beginning of the project now and the problem still persists, I am completely baffled. What is going on here? This is causing my windows to throw errors in design mode about being unable to locate resources.

Edit:An Update: Every few times I build the application it changes, this time it changed after changing the binding on a button on a UserControl. Before it was UserListViewModel and SettingViewModel. Now it's SettingsViewModel and MainScreenViewModel.

App.xaml :

```
<Application x:Class="HelpScoutMetrics.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:HelpScoutMetrics.ViewModel">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <vm:MainScreenViewModel x:Key="MainScreenViewModel" />
        <vm:SettingsViewModel x:Key="SettingsViewModel" />
        <vm:UserListViewModel x:Key="UserListViewModel" />
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/FlatButton.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**ViewModels:**

```
public class MainScreenViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainScreenViewModel()
    {
        QuickStatistics = new QuickStats();
        QuickStatistics.UserQuickStats = new ObservableCollection<UserQuickStat>();
        QuickStatistics.UserQuickStats.Add(new UserQuickStat() { Name = "Test", TotalConversations = 93, TotalReplies = 57 });
        ApplicationData.MainViewModel = this; // Temp for debug of issues
    }

    public static Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("MainScreenViewModel");

    public MainWindow Window { get; set; }

    private UserReport m_UserOverall;
    public UserReport UserOverall
    {
        get { return m_UserOverall; }
        set { m_UserOverall = value; RaisePropertyChanged("UserOverall"); }
    }

    private QuickStats m_QuickStatistics;
    public QuickStats QuickStatistics
    {
        get { return m_QuickStatistics; }
        set { m_QuickStatistics = value; RaisePropertyChanged("QuickStatistics"); }
    }

    private DateTime m_SelectedDate;
    public DateTime SelectedDate
    {
        get { return m_SelectedDate; }
        set { m_SelectedDate = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDate"); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<DateTime> m_SelectedDates;
    public ObservableCollection<DateTime> SelectedDates
    {
        get { return m_SelectedDates; }
        set { m_SelectedDates = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDates"); }
    }

    private bool m_EnableLoadQuickStatsButton;
    public bool EnableLoadQuickStatsButton
    {
        get { return m_EnableLoadQuickStatsButton; }
        set { m_EnableLoadQuickStatsButton = value; RaisePropertyChanged("EnableLoadQuickStatsButton"); }
    }

    private bool m_EnableLoadQuickStatsButtonTest = false;
    public bool EnableLoadQuickStatsButtonTest
    {
        get { return m_EnableLoadQuickStatsButtonTest; }
        set { m_EnableLoadQuickStatsButtonTest = value; RaisePropertyChanged("EnableLoadQuickStatsButtonTest"); }
    }

    public void NewUser()
    {
        QuickStatistics.UserQuickStats.Add(new UserQuickStat() { Name = "Test2", TotalConversations = 953, TotalReplies = 577 });
    }

    public void OpenSettings()
    {
        if(Window.SettingsFlyout.IsOpen)
        {
            Window.SettingsFlyout.IsOpen = false;
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, "Closed Settings Flyout");
        }
        else
        {
            SettingsViewModel viewModel = Window.SettingsFlyout.DataContext as SettingsViewModel;
            viewModel.MainWindow = Window;
            viewModel.LoadSettings();
            Window.SettingsFlyout.IsOpen = true;
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, "Opened Settings Flyout");
        }
    }

    public void OpenUsersList()
    {
        if(Window.UserListFlyout.IsOpen)
        {
            Window.UserListFlyout.IsOpen = false;
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, "Closed Users List Flyout");
        }
        else
        {
            UserListViewModel viewModel = Window.UserListFlyout.DataContext as UserListViewModel;
            UserListView userListView = Window.UserListFlyoutView;
            viewModel.UserListView = userListView;
            viewModel.MainWindow = Window;
            viewModel.SetupFreshViewModel();

            Window.UserListFlyout.IsOpen = true;
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, "Opened Users List Flyout");

        }
    }

    public void OpenLogWindow()
    {
        int count = ApplicationData.MainLogEntries.LogEvents.Count;
        NLogViewerView window = new NLogViewerView();
        window.Show();
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, "Opened Log Window");
        EnableLoadQuickStatsButtonTest = true;
    }

    public void RefreshView()// Temp for debug of issues
    {
        foreach (string name in MiscMethods.GetPropertyNames(this))
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(name);
        }
    }
}

public class SettingsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SettingsViewModel()
    {
        SettingsWindowLogic.LoadSettings(this);
    }

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("SettingsViewModel");

    public MainWindow MainWindow { get; set; }

    private string m_APIKey;
    public string APIKey
    {
        get { return m_APIKey; }
        set 
        { 
            m_APIKey = value; TriedToValidateKey = false; 
            KeyValidationButtonText = "Verify Key";
            VerifyButtonBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 213, 213, 213));
            ApplicationData.ApplicationSettings.ValidAPIKeyExists = false;
            RaisePropertyChanged("APIKey"); 
        }
    }

    private bool m_SaveAPIKey = true;
    public bool SaveAPIKey
    {
        get { return m_SaveAPIKey; }
        set { m_SaveAPIKey = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SaveAPIKey"); }
    }

    /*====================================================================
     *             Key Validation & Button
     * ==================================================================*/

    private bool m_ValidKey;
    public bool ValidKey
    {
        get { return m_ValidKey; }
        set 
        { 
            m_ValidKey = value;
            if(value)
            {
                KeyValidationButtonText = "Valid!";
                VerifyButtonBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 18, 145, 47));
                ApplicationData.ApplicationSettings.ValidAPIKeyExists = true;
            }
            else
            {
                KeyValidationButtonText = "Invalid";
                VerifyButtonBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 153, 18, 18));
                ApplicationData.ApplicationSettings.ValidAPIKeyExists = false;
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged("ValidKey"); 
        }
    }

    //Will be true when the eky is in process of verification
    private bool m_CurrentlyVerifyingKey;
    public bool CurrentlyVerifyingKey
    {
        get { return m_CurrentlyVerifyingKey; }
        set 
        {
            if (value)
            {
                KeyValidationButtonText = "Verifying...";
            }
            m_CurrentlyVerifyingKey = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentlyVerifyingKey");
        }
    }

    private bool m_TriedToValidateKey;
    public bool TriedToValidateKey
    {
        get { return m_TriedToValidateKey; }
        set { m_TriedToValidateKey = value; RaisePropertyChanged("TriedToValidateKey"); }
    }

    private string m_KeyValidationButtonText = "Verify Key";
    public string KeyValidationButtonText
    {
        get { return m_KeyValidationButtonText; }
        set { m_KeyValidationButtonText = value; RaisePropertyChanged("KeyValidationButtonText"); }
    }

    private Brush m_VerifyButtonBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 213, 213, 213));
    public Brush VerifyButtonBackground
    {
        get { return m_VerifyButtonBackground; }
        set { m_VerifyButtonBackground = value; RaisePropertyChanged("VerifyButtonBackground"); }
    }

    public async void VerifyAPIKey()
    {
        //Task<Paged<Mailbox>> testPull = new Task<Paged<Mailbox>>(() => client.ListMailboxes());
        Task<bool> results = new Task<bool>(() => SettingsWindowLogic.VerifyAPIKey(APIKey));
        CurrentlyVerifyingKey = true;

        results.Start();

        CurrentlyVerifyingKey = false;

        if (await results)
        {
            ValidKey = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ValidKey = false;
        }
        TriedToValidateKey = true;
    }



    public void SaveSettings()
    {
        SettingsWindowLogic.SaveSettings(this);
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Saved Settings");
        CloseFlyout();
    }

    public void LoadSettings()
    {
        SettingsWindowLogic.LoadSettings(this);
    }
    public void ResetSettings()
    {
        APIKey = string.Empty;
        SaveAPIKey = false;
        ApplicationData.ApplicationSettings.ValidAPIKeyExists = false;
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Reset Settings");
    }

    public void CloseFlyout()
    {
        MainWindow.SettingsFlyout.IsOpen = false;
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, "Closed Settings Flyout");
    }
}

public class UserListViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public UserListViewModel()
    {
       // LoadUserList();
    }

    public static Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("UserListViewModel");

    public MainWindow MainWindow { get; set; }
    public UserListView UserListView { get; set; }

    private UserList m_UserList;
    public UserList UsersList
    {
        get { return m_UserList; }
        set { m_UserList = value; RaisePropertyChanged("UsersList"); }
    }

    private List<string> m_TestItems;
    public List<string> TestItems
    {
        get { return m_TestItems; }
        set { m_TestItems = value; RaisePropertyChanged("TestItems"); }
    }

    private string m_NewUserName;
    public string NewUserName
    {
        get { return m_NewUserName; }
        set { m_NewUserName = value; RaisePropertyChanged("NewUserName"); }
    }

    private string m_HelpScoutUserListStatus = "Attempting To Load HelpScout Users...";
    public string HelpScoutUserListStatus
    {
        get { return m_HelpScoutUserListStatus; }
        set { m_HelpScoutUserListStatus = value; RaisePropertyChanged("HelpScoutUserListStatus"); }
    }

    private Brush m_HelpScoutUserListStatusColor = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 187, 95, 32));
    public Brush HelpScoutUserListStatusColor
    {
        get { return m_HelpScoutUserListStatusColor; }
        set { m_HelpScoutUserListStatusColor = value; RaisePropertyChanged("HelpScoutUserListStatusColor"); }
    }

    private bool m_HelpScoutUserListLoaded;
    public bool HelpScoutUserListLoaded
    {
        get { return m_HelpScoutUserListLoaded; }
        set 
        { 
            if(value)
            {
                HelpScoutUserListStatus = UserListWindowLogic.HelpScutUseListStringStatus[0];
                HelpScoutUserListStatusColor = UserListWindowLogic.HelpScoutUserListStatusColors[0];
                ReverifyUserList();
            }
            else
            {
                HelpScoutUserListStatus = UserListWindowLogic.HelpScutUseListStringStatus[1];
                HelpScoutUserListStatusColor = UserListWindowLogic.HelpScoutUserListStatusColors[1];
            }

            m_HelpScoutUserListLoaded = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged("HelpScoutUserListLoaded"); 
        }
    }

    private List<User> m_HelpScoutUsersList;
    public List<User> HelpScoutUsersList
    {
        get { return m_HelpScoutUsersList; }
        set { m_HelpScoutUsersList = value; RaisePropertyChanged("HelpScoutUsersList"); }
    }

    private List<string> m_HelpScoutUsersListStrings = new List<string>();
    public List<string> HelpScoutUsersListStrings
    {
        get { return m_HelpScoutUsersListStrings; }
        set { m_HelpScoutUsersListStrings = value; RaisePropertyChanged("HelpScoutUsersListStrings"); }
    }

    public async void RetrieveHelpScoutUserList()
    {
        Task<List<User>> task = new Task<List<User>>(() => UserListWindowLogic.RetrieveHelpScoutUserList());
        task.Start();
        List<User> usersList = await task;
        if(usersList != null)
        {
            HelpScoutUsersList = usersList;
            foreach(User userObject in usersList)
            {
                HelpScoutUsersListStrings.Add(userObject.Name);
            }
            HelpScoutUserListLoaded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            HelpScoutUserListLoaded = false;
        }
    }

    private User MatchUserID(string name)
    {
        return UserListWindowLogic.FindUserByName(name, HelpScoutUsersList);
    }

    public void RemoveUser()
    {
        User user = UserListView.NamesDataGrid.SelectedItem as User;
        UsersList.Users.Remove(user);
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Removed User: " + user.Name);
    }

    public void AddUser()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NewUserName) && HelpScoutUserListLoaded)
        {
            User user = MatchUserID(NewUserName);
            if(user != null)
            {
                UsersList.Users.Add(user);
                logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Added New Valid User: " + user.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                UsersList.Users.Add(new User() { Name = NewUserName });
                logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Added New User: " + NewUserName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            UsersList.Users.Add(new User() { Name = NewUserName });
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Added New User: " + NewUserName);
        }
        ClearNewUserNameTextBox();
    }

    //Clears the new user textbox
    public void ClearNewUserNameTextBox()
    {
        NewUserName = string.Empty;
    }

    public void SetupFreshViewModel()
    {
        m_HelpScoutUserListLoaded = false;
        HelpScoutUserListStatusColor = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 187, 95, 32));
        HelpScoutUserListStatus = "Attempting To Load HelpScout Users...";
        LoadUserList();
        RetrieveHelpScoutUserList();
    }

    public void SaveUserList()
    {
        UserListWindowLogic.SaveUserList(this);
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Saved Users List");
        CloseFlyout();
    }

    public void ReverifyUserList()
    {
        UserListWindowLogic.CheckUserListValidity(HelpScoutUsersList);
        LoadUserList();
    }

    public void LoadUserList()
    {
        UserList userList;
        if(ApplicationData.Users != null)
        {
            userList = XMLSerialize<UserList>.CopyData(ApplicationData.Users);
        }
        else
        {
            userList = UserListWindowLogic.CreateNewUserList();
        }
        UsersList = userList;
    }

    public void ResetUserList()
    {
        UsersList = new UserList();
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Reset Users List");
    }

    public void CloseFlyout()
    {
        MainWindow.UserListFlyout.IsOpen = false;
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, "Closed Users List Flyout");
    }
}

public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler temp = PropertyChanged;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public bool IsInDesignMode
    {
        get
        {
            var prop = DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty;
            return (bool)DependencyPropertyDescriptor
                .FromProperty(prop, typeof(FrameworkElement))
                .Metadata.DefaultValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't really help without seeing the content of those file or if you don't show us the full exception. The code you have there looks perfectly fine, but give us more detail on the NullReference exception then we might get a bit further

Comment: Sure thing, out of curiosity, where do I get more details on the exception in an XAML designer like that? I tried the whole open a 2nd instance of VS, attaching the debug to the process of VS #1 and having it break on any exception and got nothing. I'll post the internals of the ViewModels now. They are a bit messy since this is all in progress.

Comment: Normally switching to the designer offers a "Show stackstrace" in the designer, no? Potentially, you could also check the error window, if it shows the error while being in the designer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the constructor of your view model can be initialized in design time, if you're using some dependencies in the constructor that cannot be initialized in design time, you need to put it inside the condition block:  `if(!IsInDesignMode)`